# How to find out which parameter is not permitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, strong-parameters

I'm getting the error `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`, but I can't find out which parameter is causing the problem. Does anyone know how I can find out which parameter causes to raise the error `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`?

Answer (score 1):

install gem byebug and read the description > https://rubygems.org/gems/byebug. happy bug hunting